# Removing h3s in excerpt output?

Tags: excerpt

I have a custom post type and the content looks something like this:

```
<h3>Description</h3>

The Production Assistant works closely with the production team to ensure that our games ship on time and at our very high standards. You will be a part of an international team and gain valuable insight into game development from a management perspective. Aside from production, you will also expand your knowledge of different disciplines such as, engineering, design, art, human resources, administration, and information technology.
```

The problem now is that the excerpt outputs something like this now:

```
<p>Description The Production Assistant</p>
```

How can I tell WordPress to trim the h3s and the text inside them?

Comment: Do you want to remove only the `<h3>` or all `<hx>` tags?

Comment: RRikesh Only the h3 (all are OK too). And the content inside the tags as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a discussion on [WP Support Forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-content-within-the-header-tags-in-the-excerpt) that was related to your question. The [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XMJNtH6A) constains the function stated in the [other answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100836/17305).

I've decreased the priority to `5` and it works on my test theme.

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_strip_header_tags', 5);
```

If you want to target only `<h3>` you can use this regex:

```
$regex = '#(<h([3])[^>]*>)\s?(.*)?\s?(<\/h\2>)#';
```

Comment: Strange, it worked after changing the priority to 5.

Comment: I guess that something like [`wp_strip_all_tags()`](http://wpseek.com/wp_strip_all_tags/) is being called before and cleans up all tags before reaching your function.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this by pasting these code inside functions.php file under your current theme.

```
function wp_strip_header_tags( $excerpt='' ) {
    $raw_excerpt = $excerpt;
    if ( '' == $excerpt ) {
        $excerpt = get_the_content(''); 
        $excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $excerpt );
        $excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $excerpt);
        $excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $excerpt);
    }

    $regex = '#(<h([1-6])[^>]*>)\s?(.*)?\s?(<\/h\2>)#';
    $excerpt = preg_replace($regex,'', $excerpt);

    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
    $excerpt = wp_trim_words( $excerpt, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );

    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', preg_replace($regex,'', $excerpt), $raw_excerpt);
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_strip_header_tags', 99);
```

Comment: This will remove all `<h1>` to `<h6>`.

Comment: @Subharanjan Thanks, but strange, I still seeing Description The Production...Is the code above removing the content inside the headings as well?

Comment: @Subharanjan by the way its the exceprt of a custom post type called Jobs. Not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: @janoChen: Are you using the_excerpt(); ?
Try using get_the_excerpt() function inside loop. Custom post type doesn't matter here. 
$my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
echo $my_excerpt;

Comment: @Rikesh: You are correct. It will strip out h1 to h6.

This should work as you have mentioned.
$regex = '#(<h([3])[^>]*>)\s?(.*)?\s?(<\/h\2>)#';

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution on https://supersnelgezond.nl and it works like a charm:

```
function strip_heading_tags( $text ) {
$raw_excerpt = $text;
if ( '' == $text ) {
    //Retrieve the post content.
    $text = get_the_content(''); 
 
    //Strips the header tags and their content.
    $regex = '/<(h[1-6])>.*?<\/\1>/';
    $text = preg_replace($regex,'', $text);
    
    $text_length = apply_filters('text_length', 55);
    $text_more = apply_filters('text_more', '...');
    $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $text_length, $text_more );
    apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', preg_replace($regex,'', $text), $raw_excerpt);
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'strip_heading_tags', 5);
```